# Reduce size of self-loops in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I've got a graph, but the self-loops are large relative to the network, is there a way to reduce the self-loop size without changing the remainder of the graph?

Test data:

```
test.matrix=cbind(mtcars$gear,mtcars$carb)
adj.mat=get.adjacency(graph.edgelist(as.matrix(test.matrix)))
g=graph.adjacency(adj.mat,mode="undirected")
plot(g)
```

I tried changing the `curve_multiple`, to no avail, and can't find anything in the [documentation](http://igraph.org/r/doc/) relating to reducing loop size.

Comment: `plot(igraph::simplify(g))`? See `?igraph::simplify`.

Comment: If you are not bound to `igraph`, the `visNetwork` package is great and I am certain you can control the self-loop size there with the `selfReferenceSize` argument to [`visEdges()`](http://search.r-project.org/library/visNetwork/html/visEdges.html).

Comment: @lukeA, simplify helps, but ideally I would keep the the loops, just make them smaller.

Comment: @vincentmajor, I'll take a look at visNetwork. I'm not tied to igraph, was just the first place I started. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Hi @desc, have you got the solution for this problem?

Comment: @pengchy, no luck so far. I switched over to using the web-based `cytoscape.js`.

Comment: @pengchy, check out the answer by Ma Ba below if you're still looking for solutions.

Comment: Thank you desc and @Ma-ba. Later I have switch to Cytoscape. However, this solution is very helpful for the future application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option to the igraph plot function that allows you to change the size of the loops.
However, a small change to the igraph source code does the trick. You can see the igraph plot function by running

```
plot.igraph
```

You will find that the igraph plot function creates a function called  `loop`. Inside that function you will find the lines:

```
cp <- matrix(c(x0, y0, x0 + 0.4, y0 + 0.2, x0 + 0.4, 
     y0 - 0.2, x0, y0), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

you can make the loop half as wide/high by changing this to:

```
cp <- matrix(c(x0, y0, x0 + 0.2, y0 + 0.1, x0 + 0.2, 
     y0 - 0.1, x0, y0), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

[@desc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965651/desc) commented that you can temporarily make this change to the igraph plot function source code with

```
trace("plot.igraph",edit=TRUE)
```

Comment: I used `trace("plot.igraph",edit=TRUE)` to reset the source and your solution worked perfectly! Thanks for the answer.